How to calculate maximum power flow on a branch?
I'm currently reproducing the OPF results from the following paper: Adjustable Robust OPF With Renewable Energy Sources with pandapower. Since my background isn't EE, I'm striving to find how to calculate maximum power flow in a branch ( such in the constraint (3) ). The constraints are as follows:

After contacting the author of the paper, he sent me the dataset he used, but unfortunately for me, that's not very helpful since the dataset is only the original MATPOWER data format (I do have it), and still the formula to calculate the maximum power flow given the data from case14 pandapower is vague.
What I've done is multiplying the grid voltage level of the from_bus by maximum thermal current in kilo Ampere for every line to get the maximum power flow on a branch. Is what I've done correct?
